# php Exception class in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with my PHP Exception class in Laravel.

I am creating a class in \App\Services folder.

I have created some test code where I have the following:

```
if (!in_array($variables, $validParameters)) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid parameter types: ".str_replace(")(", ", ", $variables));
    }
```

And I get the following error:

```
Class 'App\Services\Exception' not found
```

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If your class is namespaced then you need to scape the Exception class name to let PHP know you are using an exception from the global namespace and not from your current namespace (App\Services).

```
  throw new \Exception(...)
```

Note the "\" character before the class name

Answer (score 0):

try this in your services file

```
use Exception;
```

Comment: That doesn't help, same problem